# Check dynamic object type by string comparison

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dynamic

What is the best way to check a base object if of certain type, myObject can have hierarchies at "n" level, I want to compare with string because myObject is dynamic and i do not have assembly access to vehicle

a) Car : Vehicle
 b) BiCycle : TwoWheeler : Vehicle
 c) Truck : Trailer : FourWheeler : Vehicle

```
dynamic myObject = someObject;
if(myObject is Vehicle)  // Works
if(myObject is "Vehicle") //How to ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a little recursive method to solve it:

```
 private bool IsVehicle(Type type)
        {
            if (type.BaseType != null)
                if (type.BaseType.FullName == "Vehicle")
                    return true;
                else
                    return IsVehicle(type.BaseType);
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: there is an error in this method. it should be `else return IsVehicle...`

Comment: i think it will also fail if you pass in the "vehicle" type.

Answer (score 2):

you could use IsAssginableFrom

```
System.Type.GetType(typeNameAsString).IsAssignableFrom(myObject.GetType())
```

that test whether myObject can be assign to a storage location of the type identified by the name (a string) held in typeNameAsString.

This will only work for types that are actually loaded and you should use the fully qualified name.

Comment: I get NullReferenceError in "System.Type.GetType(typeNameAsString)" bcos the "Vehicle" assembly is not added.

Comment: @BrazilNut it seems like you understand the reason why this code does not work as is. Why don't you just fix it yourself?

Comment: @BrazilNut it's more likely due to not using a fully qualified name I.e namespace.type.

Comment: @Rune: I did use full namespace, trying to find some other way

Comment: If the type is not in the current assembly, you need to include that too, something like `Namespace.Type, Assembly`.

Comment: @RuneFS: If you don't specify the assembly, it checks mscorlib and the currently executing assembly... but not others.